# Python iterable map, range, etc

Tags: python

Why doesn't python have a `__future__` library that replaces `map` with `imap`, `range` with `xrange`, etc.?  Is it possible to write one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [`future_builtins`](http://docs.python.org/library/future_builtins.html) module since Python 2.6:

```
from future_builtins import filter, map, zip
```

Answer (score 4):

A `__future__` import is not necessary:

```
from itertools import imap as map
range = xrange
```

**Edit**: If you want to do several of those in a single line, you can do

```
from itertools import imap as map, ifilter as filter, izip as zip
range = xrange; input = raw_input
```

Comment: great!  Can I do a bunch of these all in one line?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this, why not add the following to your PYTHONSTARTUP file?

```
import itertools
filter = itertools.ifilter
map    = itertools.imap
slice  = itertools.islice
zip    = itertools.izip
range  = xrange
input  = raw_input
```

Comment: Overwriting `slice()` by `islice()` does not seem like a good idea.  They do quite different things, and while all other renames reflect changes in Python 3.x, `slice()` and `islice()` were not changed.

Comment: `PYTHONSTARTUP` is for *interactive* sessions only http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP